# AWS S3 Request Rate Performance to Single Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Folks,
  What is the throughput limit on `GET` calls to a single object in a S3 bucket?  The AWS documentation suggests implementing CloudFront, however, they do not cover the case when a single object exists in a bucket.  Does anyone know if the same applies, ie ~300 GET requests/sec?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note: as of July 17 2018, the request limits have been dramatically increased along with the auto-partitioning of s3 buckets.

More information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-s3-announces-increased-request-rate-performance/?sc_channel=em&sc_campaign=&sc_publisher=aws&sc_medium=em_&sc_content=launch_la_nontier1&sc_country=&sc_geo=&sc_category=mult&sc_outcome=launch&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTW1ObE1HTmhZV05tTkRoayIsInQiOiJKUTJJQXpsTUJhM1loZnRSUTZrUjR4TWJHT20wTXhrdEdGUGpWcCtjUjV6c2dYUUcxY1wvbitIRmllNUFBVzNOOHk2VFNJdTI5NDhaWXY4Qys2b0p1SHQrRU5OcWtpcTF0bGx3aXZQR2tiRElsODE0VlFzSnJsbkRSbnRXc0M5TmtibTZFXC9Kc2d1SUNwQ0N0bldkN3AzQT09In0%3D)

Answer (score 1):

There is **no throughput limit applied** on objects in Amazon S3. However, a high rate of requests per second may limit the ability for S3 to respond to queries. As per the documentation you linked, this will only be of concern above 300 requests per second.

Larger objects can therefore provide more **throughput** than smaller objects at the same number of requests per second.

**Amazon CloudFront** can provide faster responses because information is cached rather than served directly from Amazon S3. CloudFront also has **over 50 edge locations** throughout the world, allowing it to serve content in parallel from multiple locations and at lower latency compared to S3.